# How to avoid error when someone types wrong information on a variable?

Tags: java, variables

I'm new here so pardon me if there's anything wrong on my question or if it's in the wrong section. I'm practicing Java right now and I wanna know how to do that. Here's the code:

```
package train;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Train {

public static double sum(double n1, double n2){
    double sum = n1 + n2;

    return sum;
}

public static double subtraction(double n1, double n2){
    double subtraction = n1 - n2;

    return subtraction;
}

public static double mult(double n1, double n2){
    double mult = n1 * n2;

    return mult;
}

public static double div(double n1, double n2){
    double div = n1 / n2;

    return div;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int choice;
    boolean stay = true;
    double val1, val2;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (stay = true){
        System.out.println("Selecione a operação desejada.");
        System.out.println("1 - Adição, 2 - Subtração, 3 - Multiplicação, 4 - Divisão; Pressione 0 para sair.");
        choice = sc.nextInt();

        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Digite dois valores a serem somados: ");
                val1 = sc.nextDouble();
                val2 = sc.nextDouble();

                double valsum = sum(val1, val2);

                System.out.printf("A soma desses dois valores é %f. ", valsum);
            break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Digite dois valores a serem subtraídos: ");
                val1 = sc.nextDouble();
                val2 = sc.nextDouble();

                double valsubtraction = subtraction(val1, val2);

                System.out.printf("A subtração desses dois valores é %f. ", valsubtraction);
            break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Digite dois valores a serem multiplicados: ");
                val1 = sc.nextDouble();
                val2 = sc.nextDouble();

                double valmult = mult(val1, val2);

                System.out.printf("A multiplicação desses dois valores é %f. ", valmult);
            break;

            case 4:
                System.out.println("Digite dois valores a serem divididos: ");
                val1 = sc.nextDouble();
                val2 = sc.nextDouble();

                double valdiv = div(val1, val2);

                System.out.printf("A divisão desses dois valores é %f. ", valdiv);
            break;

            case 0:
                System.exit(0);
            break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Esta não é uma operação válida.");
            break;
        }
    }
}

}
```

When the user types something other than "accepted" information on any of the variables (like typing text on the 'double' variables), the program gives an error. Is it possible avoid that?

If so, how can I do that?

Comment: You can catch `InputMismatchException` with the current code you have, or parse the input as `String` and parse your data from it if you want more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can [use a try catch statement](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/try-catch-in-java/) to catch errors then restart your while loop with a new prompt to the user.

Answer (score 0):

The class Scanner most likely is throwing some exception when is not reading an int. As a start you can

```
        try{
            choice = sc.nextInt();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e){
            choice=-1;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And try to use a debugger to trace the program execution.

Comment: You'll want to narrow down the exception type to `InputMismatchException`, so that you don't catch things you don't want to

Answer (score 0):

Just simple example. if the user entered mismatched input type value. the variable will get a negative value. which is -1

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    system.out.println("Enter a double number: ");
    double number;
    while (number <=0){

       try{
           number = input.nextDouble();
       }
       catch(InputMismatchException ex){
            System.out.println("Please Enter a valid number");
        }
       input.nextLine(); // clears the buffer


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One should normally check with one of the has* methods. Strange that everyone wants to catch exceptions.

```
      while (!sc.hasNextDouble()) {
          System.out.println("Bonvolu tajpi nombron");
          sc.next(); // Discard the rubbish.
      }
      val1 = sc.nextDouble();

      while (!sc.hasNextDouble()) {
          System.out.println("Bonvolu tajpi nombron");
          sc.next(); // Discard the rubbish.
      }
      val2 = sc.nextDouble();
```

While not "has scanned a next double" keep reading the unspecific "next" token.

One might use a function to prevent code copies.

```
private static double scanDouble(Scanner sc, String errorMessage) {
    while (!sc.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println(errorMessage);
        sc.next(); // Discard the rubbish.
    }
    return sc.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the java.util.Scanner class is a great place to start for this question:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

When reviewing the methods therein, you’ll find that Scanner supports a series of methods for testing the datatype of input tokens, which are the hasNextXXXX() methods (hasNextFloat(), hasNextDouble(), etc.).  Using these methods, you can perform conditional checks on the input provided by the user and use these checks to determine whether to consume and operate on the provided value, or to notify the user that the input was invalid.  A trivial example:

```
package inputtest;

public class InputTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter an integer value: ");

        while(scanner.hasNext()) { 
            if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                int x = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Thanks for the integer; you provided: " + x);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, you did not provide and integer value.");
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Obviously you could opt to re-prompt for input rather than break here, but the methods are the same.